# Not receiving all record in Apollo graphql

Tags: android, graphql, apollo

IN pagination code i set limit 5 but in response getting random count like 1, 3, 4, 5.
in play ground api working right way.
please help me to sort out this issue.

```
 public LiveData<GetPublicPostByUserIDQuery.Data> getPublicPost(int userId,int limmit,int offset,int loginUserId) {

        final MutableLiveData<GetPublicPostByUserIDQuery.Data> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        ApolloConnector.setupApollo().query(GetPublicPostByUserIDQuery
                .builder()
                .userId(userId)
                .plimit(limmit)
                .pOffset(offset)
                .logInUserID(loginUserId)

                .build()
        )
                .enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<GetPublicPostByUserIDQuery.Data>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull Response<GetPublicPostByUserIDQuery.Data> response) {
                       

                  data.postValue(response.data());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(ApolloException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "webservice fail:: ",e);
                       
                    }
                });

        return data;

    }
```

public class ApolloConnector {

```
public static ApolloClient setupApollo(){

    NormalizedCacheFactory cacheFactory = new LruNormalizedCacheFactory(EvictionPolicy.builder().maxSizeBytes(10 * 1024 * 1024).build());
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    return ApolloClient.builder().serverUrl(BASE_URL).normalizedCache(cacheFactory).okHttpClient(okHttpClient).build();
}
```

}

Comment: It would be great if you could share some more details on how you are calling the API.

Comment: please check and help me